# N1ql to fetch Index definition

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am working on getting all indexes scripted from one environment from other.
I can get indexes names from below query by specifying bucket:

```
select RAW name from system:indexes where keyspace_id=‘namedDB’
```

Now my question is there any way that i can get Index definition using N1ql as in sql server we used to do
sp_helptext’Indexname’
It will show index definition.Is there any way in N1ql.If not how to extract definition of all indexes at once rather than going one by one.

Thanks
Ritz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct statement in the N1QL. You need to build the statement using system:indexes.

You Can try one of the following option

1. Run the following command on each index node
   https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.5/rest-api/get-statement-indexes.html

   ```
   curl -v Administrator:password@127.0.0.1:9102/getIndexStatement
   ```
2. Use UI copy all definitions
3. Checkout cbbackupmgr  https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.5/backup-restore/cbbackupmgr-restore.html
4. Add whitelist described in Security section of https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/curl.html

   SELECT RAW re 
   FROM CURL("http://Administrator:password@127.0.0.1:9102/getIndexStatement",{}) AS re  ;

Comment: Thanks Vsr already using above methods given by you but wanted if we can precise it to more at query level.